# EclipseLink JPA Dynamic model and Criteria Query

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, jpa-2.0

i like to create a (crtieria-) query against a dynamic model but i always get the exception

```
No [EntityType] was found for the key class [demo.DynamicResult] in the Metamodel
```

at the last line

```
final CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();

final CriteriaQuery<Tuple> query = criteriaBuilder.createTupleQuery();   
DynamicHelper helper = new DynamicHelper(JpaHelper.getServerSession(emf));
Class<? extends DynamicEntity> rootclass = helper.getType("demo.DynamicResult").getJavaClass();
query.from(rootclass);
```

The DynamicResult gets generated with following code

```
ServerSession serverSession = JpaHelper.getEntityManager(entityManager).getServerSession();
DynamicClassLoader dcl = DynamicClassLoader.lookup(serverSession);
JPADynamicHelper jpaDynamicHelper = new JPADynamicHelper(entityManager);
Class<?> dynamicResult = dcl.createDynamicClass("demo.DynamicResult");

JPADynamicTypeBuilder dynamicResultBuilder = new JPADynamicTypeBuilder(dynamicResult, null, "DynamicResult");

dynamicResultBuilder.addDirectMapping("id", String.class, "id");

        //Some more addDirectMappings ....

dynamicResultBuilder.setPrimaryKeyFields("id");
type = dynamicResultBuilder.getType();
jpaDynamicHelper.addTypes(false, false, type);
```

What did I missed ? 
Is this kind of query possible at all ?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be hitting https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=429760 bug. There was a problem with copying newly created dynamic entity metadata into current session.
Check this bug and attached diffs. jpa/eclipselink.jpa.test/src/org/eclipse/persistence/testing/tests/jpa/dynamic/simple/SimpleQueryTestSuite.java test suite contains test which does similar thing - creates dynamic entity and runs JPQL query against it within the same transaction (UnitOfWork).
I would try latest 2.7.0 or 2.6.1 (do not use .WAS) build from https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/nightly.php to see if it works fine for you.